# Grouping Alerts in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to group alerts based on notificationSubject. If
> notificationSubject key value length(dosMinus) > 1 means it will
> display in first div and  notificationSubject key value length (DOS
> etc) == 1 means it will display in second div For example, following
> json contains notificationSubject = dosMinus are there in 2 times and
> remaining each one record. I want to display 'dosMinus' in 1st div and
> remaining alerts in 2nd div.

** -->

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.alerts = {
        "DISPLAY_ALERT_DETAILS": [
            {
                "alertRaisedUserId": 1215
                , "source": 1
                , "clientTimestamp": 1492732800000
                , "severity": "low"
                , "createdByMe": "Y"
                , "notificationSubject": "dosMinus"
                , "notificationDetails": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
    }

        , {
                "alertRaisedUserId": 1215
                , "source": 1
                , "clientTimestamp": 1492732800000
                , "severity": "low"
                , "createdByMe": "Y"
                , "notificationSubject": "dosMinus"
                , "notificationDetails": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
    }

        , {
                "alertRaisedUserId": 1215
                , "source": 1
                , "clientTimestamp": 1492992000000
                , "severity": "low"
                , "createdByMe": "Y"
                , "notificationSubject": "DOS"
                , "notificationDetails": "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
    }
        , {
                "alertRaisedUserId": 1215
                , "source": 1
                , "clientTimestamp": 1492992000000
                , "severity": "informational"
                , "createdByMe": "Y"
                , "notificationSubject": "EO"
                , "notificationDetails": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing"
    }
        , {
                "alertRaisedUserId": 1215
                , "source": 1
                , "clientTimestamp": 1492992000000
                , "severity": "informational"
                , "createdByMe": "Y"
                , "notificationSubject": "Late Sales Orders"
                , "notificationDetails": "It has survived not only five centuries"
    }
        , {
                "alertRaisedUserId": 1215
                , "source": 1
                , "clientTimestamp": 1492992000000
                , "severity": "informational"
                , "createdByMe": "Y"
                , "notificationSubject": "Late Purchase Orders"
                , "notificationDetails": "It was popularised in the 1960s with "
    }
        , {
                "alertRaisedUserId": 1215
                , "source": 1
                , "clientTimestamp": 1492992000000
                , "severity": "informational"
                , "createdByMe": "Y"
                , "notificationSubject": "Demand"
                , "notificationDetails": "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing "
    }
        , {
                "alertRaisedUserId": 1215
                , "source": 1
                , "clientTimestamp": 1492992000000
                , "severity": "informational"
                , "createdByMe": "Y"
                , "notificationSubject": "Spend"
                , "notificationDetails": "more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    }
        , {
                "alertRaisedUserId": 1215
                , "source": 1
                , "clientTimestamp": 1492992000000
                , "severity": "informational"
                , "createdByMe": "Y"
                , "notificationSubject": "Inventory"
                , "notificationDetails": "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset "
    }
    ]
    }
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head> </head>

<body ng-controller="myctrl">
    <div> 1. Div (Display dosMinus)</div>
    <div> 2. Div (Display DOS....Etc)</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I want to display 'dosMinus' in 1st div and > remaining alerts in 2nd div.

Here's the simple code using `ng-if`:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
  <head> </head>
  <body ng-controller="myctrl" ng-repeat="a in alerts.DISPLAY_ALERT_DETAILS">
    <div> 1. Div <span ng-if="a.notificationSubject == 'dosMinus'">{{a.notificationSubject}}</span></div>
    <div> 2. Div <span ng-if="a.notificationSubject != 'dosMinus'">{{a.notificationSubject}}</span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

To select based on no. of occurence of each `notificationSubject`, you'll have to get count of each and based on that selectively use div1 of div2 using `ng-if`.

Here the JS code to set and get count:

```
var count = {};
$scope.alerts = ...//your JSON

for(var i=0;i<$scope.alerts.DISPLAY_ALERT_DETAILS.length;i++) {
    setCount($scope.alerts.DISPLAY_ALERT_DETAILS[i].notificationSubject);
}

function setCount(notSub) {
    if(count[notSub]) {
        count[notSub]++;
    }
    else {
        count[notSub] = 1;
    }
}
$scope.getCount = function(notSub) {
    return count[notSub];
}
```

and to conditionally use div's, you can call `$scope.getCount` from HTML to get count.

```
<body ng-controller="myctrl" ng-repeat="a in alerts.DISPLAY_ALERT_DETAILS">
  <div> 1. Div <span ng-if="getCount(a.notificationSubject)>1">{{a.notificationSubject}}</span></div>
  <div> 2. Div <span ng-if="getCount(a.notificationSubject) == 1">{{a.notificationSubject}}</span></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Notificationsubject length greater than one means it will display in first div and Notificationsubject length equal to 1 then it will display in second div. current json contains dosMinus in two times then your condition is ok.but DOS and EO and Riskscore also will come two or more times. we need to display more than one record display in first div and remaining display in second div.

Comment: What do you mean by Notificationsubject length? Length of string value for Notificationsubject e.g `'dosMinus'.length = 8`, or number of times dosMinus occurs in JSON, which is 2 in this case, and 1 for everything else?

Comment: Number of times dosminus occurs occurs in Json

Comment: In that case, you need to calculate occurence of each `notificationSubject`. Check the updated code.

Comment: Fantastic Mind blowing Unbelievable ......................................   Thanks Bro

Comment: Accept this as answer and upvote if this solved your problem.